# Create SQLite3 table from BASH Array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, sqlite

I am trying to create a table from an array in bash.  I have figured out how to get it to create the array from a text file, but then creating the table either doesn't work or it only uses the last value from the array.   Am I trying to do something that is not possible?

My script:

```
readarray -t array < file.txt
for e in "${array[@]}" 
do 
DB_PATH="" 
DB_NAME=$DB_PATH"Test.db" 
sqlite3 $DB_NAME << EOF 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblA;
CREATE TABLE tblA(A,B,C);
INSERT INTO tblA (A,B) SELECT tblB.A,tblB.B,1 FROM tblB WHERE tblB.D="$e"; 
EOF
done
```

I've also tried `WHERE tblB.D="${array[@]}";`

EDITED to include entire SQL code.

Comment: I am no expert in SQL, but If you have dropped the table, I don't believe you can do an `INSERT ... WHERE` because nothing is anything anywhere if you have dropped the table. You may not be able to use WHERE with INSERT at all.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The old table is dropped and then recreated with the new array values.  The WHERE statement does work in an INSERT, just not in this case.  If I call out each value in the array specifically     WHERE tblB.D="${array[0]}" OR WHERE tblB.D= "${array[1]}", etc, it will work; however, I would prefer to not have to call them out specifically when there are 100+ values in the array.

Comment: Maybe show your full code so I can understand...

Comment: Why can't you just use `.import`?

Comment: OK - I'm going to try to add the code in again (kept getting an error last week so I just put the note in).  @CL. I can't just use the .import because the text file contains that variables that are used to query tblB to create tblA.

Comment: This code tries to insert three values into two columns.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the table gets recreated (i.e., emptied) in every loop iteration.

Create the table only once. Inside the loop, do only the INSERT.

Comment: Ugh!  I knew it would be something simple that needed to be fixed/added, but I didn't expect it to be in the SQLite script!  Thank you!  I was still having an issue with the script, but this definitely helped.

Answer (score 1):

While the primary key continues to increment rather than start over (a minor issue), this script is working:

```
sqlite3 Test.db "DELETE FROM tblA;"

getArray() {
    array=()
    while IFS= read -r line
    do
         array+=("$line")
    done < "$1"
    }

getArray "file.txt"

for e in "${array[@]}"
do
    DB_PATH="" 
    DB_NAME=$DB_PATH"Test.db" 
    sqlite3 $DB_NAME << EOF 
    INSERT INTO tblA (A,B) SELECT tblB.A,tblB.B,1 FROM tblB WHERE tblB.D="$e"; 

EOF

done
```

Comment: Putting the sqlite3 Test.db "DROP TABLE...." and sqlite3 Test.db "CREATE TABLE...." above the "getArray" fixed the primary key increment "issue" and the insert still works correctly.